# Blank Project Selection pane when adding android-support-v7-appcompat to a project on Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-appcompat

For some reason I deleted my eclipse ADT bundle folder, downloaded a new one and created a new workspace for this new instance. After importing a project from the previous workspace into the new one, it started showing the error '**No resource found that matches the given name 'theme.appcompat.***'. After searching online, many answers suggest Right clicking on the project explorer >> ***Properties***>>***Android***>>***Library***>>***Add***>> then selecting android-support-v7-appcompat. For my case the ***Project Selection*** pane where I am supposed to select is blank!! After 3 hours of searching, I found a solution as below. I find it worth sharing here because no question answers this specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

From Eclipse, click on **File**>>**Import**>>**General**>>**Existing project into workspace**.
Browse to to your previous workspace and select ***appcompat_v7*** folder. Restart eclipse after you finish.
Now when you click on your project on the project explorer>>**Properties**>>**Android**>>**Library**>>**Add**, you will see ***android-support-v7-appcompat*** listed, select it and continue. This is also a solution to the problem '***

> No resource found that matches the given name 'theme.appcompat.*

***' especially after migrating to a new workspace.